# Member name lookup rules

Tags: c++, class, language-lawyer

The sec. 10.2 describes member name lookup rules:

10.2/3:

> The lookup set for f in C, called S(f, C), consists of two component
>   sets: the declaration set, a set of members named f; and the subobject
>   set, a set of subobjects where declarations of these members (possibly
>   including using-declarations) were found. In the declaration set,
>   using-declarations are replaced by the members they designate, and
>   type declarations (including injected-class-names) are replaced by the
>   types they designate. S(f, C) is calculated as follows:

10.2/4:

> If C contains a declaration of the name f, the declaration set
>   contains every declaration of f declared in C that satisfies the
>   requirements of the language construct in which the lookup occurs.

Consider the following two examples:

```
class A
{
    void foo(){ A::a; } //S(a, A)={ static const int a; }
    static const int a = 5;
}
```

and

```
class A
{
    int b[A::a]; //S(a, A) is empty and the program is ill-formed
    static const int a = 5;
}
```

What is the actual S(f, C) calculation rules and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these code snippets

```
class A
{
    void foo(){ A::a; } //S(a, A)={ static const int a; }
    static const int a = 5;
};

class A
{
    int b[A::a]; //S(a, A) is empty and the program is ill-formed
    static const int a = 5;
};
```

you should consider the name lookup that is described in section `3.4 Name lookup` of the Standard. They have nothing common with the quotes you cited. Though I can show what is S(f, C) for example for name A::a in the first class definition. So S( a, A ) cosists only from one declaration `static const int a = 5`

Take into account that in the second class definition name `A::a` will not be found because it has to be declared before its usage.

The other rule is used for the name lookup in member functions. In the first class definition name A::a will be found.

All this is described in section 3.4 of the Standard as I pointed out.

As for the phrase you cited then the more appropriate example will be for example the following

```
struct A
{
   void f( int );
};

struct B : A
{
   using f;
   void f( char );
};
```

In this case if the name f is searched then S( f, B ) will contain two declarations

```
using f; // or void f( int );
```

and

```
void f( char );
```

Comment: I don't agree with `They have nothing common with the quotes you cited.` It is because 3.4.3.1/1 said: `If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the name specified after the nested-namespecifier is looked up in the scope of the class (10.2)`. This implies that the member name lookup will be applied in my code snippets. Am I right?

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv This case consideres situations when the class is a complete type that is when the class is already defined.

Comment: But it is not said about completeness of class type in the 10.2 something. So I'm assume this rules applied to both complete and incomplete class types.

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv I agree with you that this place of the Standard is ambiguous.