# Injected-class-name denoted incomplete and complete type

Tags: c++, class, language-lawyer

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class A
{
    void foo(){ A a; }//1.  Ok, because A is complete type here
    int b[A::c];//2. Error, because incomplete type denoted by A does not contain c as a member.
    static const int c = 6;
}
```

With respect to that behavior I assume that A in `//1` and in `//2` actually refers to the different entity. But during the name lookup process (3.4.1, unqualified name lookup) for the `A` the same ***injected class name*** will be found both in `//1` and in `//2`. It is very curious.

Can you explain that?

I would like to find a normative reference from the Standard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class member qualified name lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299963/class-member-qualified-name-lookup)

Comment: @40two No, these questions is the different.

Comment: Closely related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293917/member-name-lookup-rules

Comment: @40two I'm interested in why does the same declaration of the injected-class-name actually denoted the different entity depends on context?

Comment: @40two Can you read my question entirely?

Comment: @40two From the identity of the code examples does not implies identity of the questions.

Comment: [basic.types]/6 "A class type (such as `class X`) might be incomplete at one point in a translation unit and complete later
on; the type `class X` is the same type at both points." So I would say both `A`s refer to the *same entity*.

Comment: @dyp But complete and incomplete class type at //1 and //2 contains the different members. I don't understand how does these types can be the same?

Comment: Because at one points it's incomplete. Once it has been completed, it will always have the same members. Note that "the same type" as well as "the same entity" are just relations with some definition; even though the `A`s behave differently at those two points they can still be "the same" as defined by those relations.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: The member functions dont contribute the size of the class, thus they exist as if they're outside the class.

Comment: Oh, if I remember correctly, the whole notion of *member function bodies being parsed after the end of the class definition* is not pointed out very well in the Standard. It only says that *name lookup* inside member functions can find members declared later in the class. Nevertheless, one reasons about this program typically by placing the function body outside of the class body (just after the end of the class definition). This has been specified intentionally so that it doesn't make a difference where the function body is placed.

Answer (score 0):

dyp already gave the correct answer in the comments section. Quoting from the standard:

> A class type (such as "`class X`") might be incomplete at one point in a translation unit and complete later on; the type "`class X`" is the same type at both points. [...]

This is [basic.types.general]/6 in C++20, although the wording hasn't changed since C++98. This is the normative reference that the OP asked for.

The OP then asked:

> But complete and incomplete class type at //1 and //2 contains the different members. I don't understand how does these types can be the same?

They're the same in terms of *identity*, just like how a person with two arms and two legs is the same person later on if they have had the misfortune of losing one of their arms.